# Rails app can't find connect to postgres after working on a different app for a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

So I just need to direction on understanding a postgres installation better, because clearly I only know enough to be dangerous.

I had an app that was my project with a postgres DB installed via homebrew

Then I started collaborating on a project with other people

There was some difficulty getting my existing prostgres install to work with the new project so I installed the postgres app with the gui interface to start stop the db.

That new project is finished and I wanted to get back to work on my other project

When I started the first app up, it couldn't find a db. I tried drop the db, and recreating it, but when I run the migrations it says the tables already exist.

What can I do to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach would be using Docker so everyone have the same environment. This would mean even you, across your machines or your working colleagues or collaborators would have the same environment. You could have many containers running (watching exposing different ports for Postgres, i.e: 5433...) and when a project finishes just get rid of the container.

This approach saves you the overhead of having to maintain multiple databases locally or depending on a running Postgres process (which I sometimes forget to start).

If you need to solve this locally, try starting your postgres service, connecting to your localhost instance and running:

```
> psql
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

> \l
```

and you should see all of your databases and debug them. Perhaps deleting and creating the conflicting database (if you don't need your local data) could help.